# How can I loop over my pushd stack?

Tags: bash, xargs

My motivation is that I'm working with multiple git repositories, and I want to run `git status` on all of them to see what's what.

As I switch between repositories quite often, I have them in a `pushd` stack, shown by `dirs -v` to be:

```
0  /d/dev/helperscripts
1  /d/dev/mainsite
2  /d/dev/satellitesite
3  /d/dev/apithing
```

I've tried looping over them using `xargs` as follows:

```
dirs | xargs -n 1 -I % bash -c 'cd -- "%" && git status '
```

However, this gives the following error:

> `bash: line 0: cd: /d/dev/helperscripts /d/dev/mainsite /d/dev/satellitesite /d/dev/apithing: No such file or directory`

I find this surprising as the result of the following is a line-break'd list of the directories as expected:

```
dirs | xargs -n 1 echo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **dirs** command prints a list of directories on the stack separated by a space, but when using **xargs** with the `-I` option, **xargs** expects the input to be separated by a newline. Use the `-p` option to **dirs** to return the stack with one directory per line, which will give **xargs** what it wants.

In addition, Bash will normally substitute your home directory with a `~` in the **dirs** listing. This may cause your command to fail because the substitution encloses the directory in quotes, and `~` loses its special meaning when quoted. Use the `-l` option to **dirs** to force it to always return full, unabbreviated paths.

```
dirs -p -l | xargs -n 1 -I % bash -c 'cd -- "%" && git status '
```

EDIT:

My original solution was intended to answer the main question of why **xargs** was choking on the output of **dirs**. However, as Ole Tange rightly pointed out in the comments, it still suffers from not properly handling directory names with spaces or other shell metacharacters in them. This is precisely the problem that `xargs -0` was intended solve, but Bash provides no convenient way to display the directory stack using NULL as a delimiter.

One alternative would instead be to loop over the `$DIRSTACK` array, which contains the same list that **dirs** would produce:

```
function dirs_git_status
{
    for d in "${DIRSTACK[@]}"
    do
        git --git-dir="${d}/.git" --work-tree="$d" status
    done
}
```

The `"${DIRSTACK[@]}"` notation ensures that each complete array element is copied in to `$d`, and as long as `$d` is used inside double-quotes within the loop, metacharacters should be preserved and passed to **git** as-is instead of being evaluated by Bash.

Comment: Fails with: bash: line 0: cd: ~/tmp/iw: No such file or directory

Comment: It fails the command specifies `"%"` (which I copied verbatim from your example). This expands to `"~/tmp/iw"`, and `~` loses its special meaning when used inside quotes. The solution for that is `dirs -l`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Fails when used on crazy dirs with: bash: line 0: cd: /home/tange/tmp/<#&|()!!: No such file or directory

Comment: When using xargs always test your solution on input starting with -, containing multiple spaces, " and '.  E.g. `mkdir -- -\"\ \ \'`

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU Parallel this will also work:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
# Make some crazy dirs
mkdir -- -a'" "'"' '"b '<#&|()$@!!'
pushd -- -a*b
pushd ..
pushd '<#&|()$@!!'
pushd ../..

dirs -p | parallel cd -- '{= s/^~/$ENV{HOME}/ =}' '&&' pwd
dirs -p -l | parallel cd -- {} '&&' pwd
```